# nginx, passenger, rails: no such file to load --bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I set up an OSX webserver for an rails application running on nginx.
When I manually start the server, the rails app works fine, but when I restart the server I always get the passenger error message

> No such file to load --bundler

I guess it has to do something with the Launch Daemon I set up manually:

```
# /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.nginx.ngnx.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>nginx</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>MyUser</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.0.11/sbin/nginx</string>
        <string>-g</string>
        <string>daemon off;</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NetworkState</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you see, I use `MyUser` as UserName in the plist. The nginx server starts after boot and runs as MyUser, but I get this error message.

When I restart it on the command line using `sudo nginx -s stop && nginx` everything works fine.

Any ideas why?

***edit***

my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
env GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems;
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout     60 60;
  send_timeout          120;

  recursive_error_pages on;

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 32 16k;

  #server_tokens off;
  tcp_nopush    on;
  tcp_nodelay   on;
  keepalive_requests 0;

  passenger_default_user eveadmin;
  passenger_default_group staff;
  passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/passenger-3.0.12;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby;


  server {
     listen 8444;
     #server_name intranet.local;
     root /Users/eveadmin/rails/intranet/public;
     passenger_enabled on;
     rails_env development;
  }
}
```

[image: error i get]

Comment: Is bundler actually installed? How is Ruby installed?

Comment: everything works when i start nginx manually, the problem is that nginx does not start up correct when the machine boots up. so yes, bundler is installed. installed ruby using homebrew / rvm.

Comment: It sounds like an environment issue. How does your nginx.conf look like?

Comment: .....anybody has another idea?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: Try setting the GEM_HOME environment variable in your nginx config.

Comment: unfortunately this does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting passenger_default_user and passenger_default_group in your nginx.conf.

The default value is nobody, which may have caused your issues.

Refer to [Phusion Passenger users guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerDefaultUser) for more details.

Comment: thanks, but it did not help, i updated my nginx conf in the original post

Comment: actually I think the nginx.conf is okay because if i start manually it works. I think the problem is due to the /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.nginx.ngnx.plist

Answer (score 0):

Did you use sudo when you installed rubygems or bundler? If so, try reinstalling them locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue as well with bundler. In certain environments, if I run bundle w/ sudo I will get the error you are seeing and if I run it w/o sudo then it works fine.

I believe that it may be because your `$PATH` and `$GEM_HOME` variables are not set b/c your user's shell environment (probably bash) isn't loaded. Maybe you should change your command to something like this:

```
/bin/bash -l -c '/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.0.11/sbin/nginx'
```

If that doesn't work, have you tried taking the UserName key out of your launch daemon and see what happens?

Comment: you could try adding a daemon that does /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $PATH >> somelogfile.log' and checking the contents of the log file